# ExcelDataReader Invalid Signature

Tags: c#, exceldatareader

I'm trying to do some benchmark of uploading and inserting data from Excel file. But before I read the file, I get an exception "Invalid Signature". What is strange, same code in application when I'm really uploading and inserting data in database is working.
Here is code:

```
    [Benchmark]
    public async Task Import()
        {
           Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        var requests = new List<MilkPaymentImportRequest>();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Family\Desktop\ImportTest.xls", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            FileUpload fileUpload = new FileUpload();
            fileUpload.File = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, stream.Name, stream.Name);
            await fileUpload.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)
            {

                var firstRowHeader = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (firstRowHeader > 0)
                    {
                        var year = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                        var month = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(1));
                        var accountId = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(2));
                        var name = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(3));
                        var invoice = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(4));
                        var commitments = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(5));
                        var payable = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.GetValue(6));
                        var reference = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(7));
                        var iban = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(8));

                        var factoryId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        var farmId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                        requests.Add(new MilkPaymentImportRequest
                        {
                            AccountId = accountId,
                            Name = name,
                            Commitments = commitments,
                            IBAN = iban,
                            Invoice = invoice,
                            Month = month,
                            Year = year,
                            Payable = payable,
                            ReferenceNumber = reference,
                            FarmId = farmId,
                            FactoryId = factoryId
                        });
                    }

                    firstRowHeader++;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Do I miss some configuration or I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: The database and the ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader() are using different drivers (versions) to open and read the excel file

Comment: Try maybe with ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader() because thats only to create XLS format. Also if you have some problems with reading try to give permissions to folder where is that file

Comment: I had tried with that also, it is not a problem with permissions.

Comment: Found the problem, File.Create had corrupt  me the file. When I changed to File.Open and create new file, everything work fine.